# Trouble with HBase / Zookeeper installation

Tags: installation, connection, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have a problem with installing hbase on Ubuntu 11.04. I'm new to ubuntu and actually a noob! Recently, I installed hadoop-0.20.2 on my laptop with single cluster configurations, and I ran WordCount example on it and it worked fine. Then, I tried installing hbase-0.90.3 as it is described in [HBase quickstart](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html). When I started hbase and tried `create 'test', 'cf'` (the shell exercises) I got this error:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: HBase is able to
connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately. This could be a sign
that the server has too many connections (30 is the default). Consider inspecting
your ZK server logs for that error and then make sure you are reusing
HBaseConfiguration as often as you can. See HTable's javadoc for more information.

Here is some help for this command:
Create table; pass table name, a dictionary of specifications per
column family, and optionally a dictionary of table configuration.
Dictionaries are described below in the GENERAL NOTES section.
Examples:
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
  hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true}
```

This is the log that hbase makes in logs folder: (the file `hbase-sepideh-master-sepideh.log` in my case)

```
Thu Jul 28 10:43:57 IRDT 2011 Starting master on sepideh
ulimit -n 1024
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:host.name=sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.version=1.6.0_26
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.class.path=/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../conf:/usr//lib/tools.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/..:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../hbase-0.90.3.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../hbase-0.90.3-tests.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/avro-1.3.3.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/guava-r06.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/hadoop-core-0.20-append-r1056497.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/thrift-0.2.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.name=Linux
2011-07-28 10:43:57,877 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2011-07-28 10:43:57,878 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:os.version=2.6.38-10-generic
2011-07-28 10:43:57,878 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.name=sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:57,878 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.home=/home/sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:57,878 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:user.dir=/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3
2011-07-28 10:43:57,892 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /tmp/hbase-sepideh/zookeeper/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir /tmp/hbase-sepideh/zookeeper/zookeeper/version-2
2011-07-28 10:43:57,915 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2011-07-28 10:43:57,920 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog: Snapshotting: 0
2011-07-28 10:43:57,987 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:37627
2011-07-28 10:43:57,990 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Processing stat command from /127.0.0.1:37627
2011-07-28 10:43:57,997 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Stat command output
2011-07-28 10:43:57,998 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37627 (no session established for client)
2011-07-28 10:43:57,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster: Started MiniZK Server on client port: 2181
2011-07-28 10:43:58,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRpcMetrics: Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster, port=44109
2011-07-28 10:43:58,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User: Skipping login, not running on secure Hadoop
2011-07-28 10:43:58,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server Responder: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server listener on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 1 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 2 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 3 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 4 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 5 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,071 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 6 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,072 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 7 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,072 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 8 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,072 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 9 on 44109: starting
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_26
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../conf:/usr//lib/tools.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/..:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../hbase-0.90.3.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../hbase-0.90.3-tests.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/avro-1.3.3.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/guava-r06.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/hadoop-core-0.20-append-r1056497.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/thrift-0.2.0.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:/home/sepideh/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2011-07-28 10:43:58,090 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.38-10-generic
2011-07-28 10:43:58,091 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:58,091 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/sepideh
2011-07-28 10:43:58,091 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/sepideh/Desktop/hbase-0.90.3
2011-07-28 10:43:58,092 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=master:44109
2011-07-28 10:43:58,101 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:43:58,102 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:37628
2011-07-28 10:43:58,102 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-07-28 10:43:58,105 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:37628
2011-07-28 10:43:58,109 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog: Creating new log file: log.1
2011-07-28 10:43:58,153 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x1316f60c4270000 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:37628
2011-07-28 10:43:58,153 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1316f60c4270000, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-07-28 10:43:58,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=Master, sessionId=sepideh:44109
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: revision
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsUser
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsDate
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsUrl
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: date
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsRevision
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: user
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: hdfsVersion
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: url
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: MetricsString added: version
2011-07-28 10:43:58,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: new MBeanInfo
2011-07-28 10:43:58,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics: new MBeanInfo
2011-07-28 10:43:58,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.metrics.MasterMetrics: Initialized
2011-07-28 10:43:58,248 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
2011-07-28 10:43:58,248 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:43:58,249 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-07-28 10:43:58,249 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:37629
2011-07-28 10:43:58,249 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:37629
2011-07-28 10:43:58,254 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x1316f60c4270001 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:37629
2011-07-28 10:43:58,254 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1316f60c4270001, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-07-28 10:43:58,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRpcMetrics: Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=HRegionServer, port=40779
2011-07-28 10:43:58,275 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User: Skipping login, not running on secure Hadoop
2011-07-28 10:43:58,277 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=regionserver:40779
2011-07-28 10:43:58,278 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:43:58,278 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2011-07-28 10:43:58,278 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:37630
2011-07-28 10:43:58,278 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:37630
2011-07-28 10:43:58,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ActiveMasterManager: Master=sepideh:44109
2011-07-28 10:43:58,287 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Established session 0x1316f60c4270002 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:37630
2011-07-28 10:43:58,288 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1316f60c4270002, negotiated timeout = 40000
2011-07-28 10:43:59,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:00,503 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:01,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:02,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:03,506 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:04,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:05,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:06,510 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:07,511 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:08,513 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
2011-07-28 10:44:08,517 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
    at $Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:193)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1700(Client.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:860)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:720)
    ... 18 more
2011-07-28 10:44:08,523 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Aborting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,523 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Stopping service threads
2011-07-28 10:44:08,523 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping server on 44109
2011-07-28 10:44:08,524 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,524 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 1 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,524 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 2 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 3 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 4 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 5 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 6 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 7 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 8 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping IPC Server listener on 44109
2011-07-28 10:44:08,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 9 on 44109: exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,529 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2011-07-28 10:44:08,550 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1316f60c4270000
2011-07-28 10:44:08,557 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2011-07-28 10:44:08,557 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1316f60c4270000 closed
2011-07-28 10:44:08,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
2011-07-28 10:44:08,557 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37628 which had sessionid 0x1316f60c4270000
2011-07-28 10:44:08,558 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37629 which had sessionid 0x1316f60c4270001
2011-07-28 10:44:08,559 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1316f60c4270001, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2011-07-28 10:44:08,560 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37630 which had sessionid 0x1316f60c4270002
2011-07-28 10:44:08,560 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1316f60c4270002, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2011-07-28 10:44:08,560 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: NIOServerCnxn factory exited run method
2011-07-28 10:44:08,561 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor: SyncRequestProcessor exited!
2011-07-28 10:44:08,561 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor: shutdown of request processor complete
2011-07-28 10:44:08,561 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: PrepRequestProcessor exited loop!
2011-07-28 10:44:09,764 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:44:09,765 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1316f60c4270001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
2011-07-28 10:44:10,000 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl: SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!
2011-07-28 10:44:10,265 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:44:10,266 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1316f60c4270002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
2011-07-28 10:44:11,766 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:44:11,767 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1316f60c4270001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
2011-07-28 10:44:11,967 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:44:11,968 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1316f60c4270002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
2011-07-28 10:44:13,265 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-07-28 10:44:13,266 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1316f60c4270002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
```

Thank you for your attention and time.

Answer (score 3):

Comment 127.0.1.1 hostname record in your /etc/hosts file

Comment: 127.0.0.1 or you eth0 Ip adress!

Answer (score 2):

Copy the hadoop-core-*.jar in hadoop folder to the hbase/lib folder.Also copy commons-configuration-1.6.jar from hadoop lib folder to hbase lib folder...This should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to HBase shell is loading the wrong config

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Running on Centos with the Cloudera packages there is an "hbase" executable in "/usr/bin".  This sets environment variables assuming that ZooKeeper is set up separately to hbase (with config files in "/usr/lib/zookeeper/conf").  In fact I'm allowing hbase to control ZooKeeper - with the ZooKeeper configuration in the hbase config files (in "/usr/lib/hbase/conf").  Running the hbase shell directly ("/usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase shell") seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the hadoop also setup? I had the same issue unsetting the hadoop home did the trick for me. `unset $HADOOP_HOME`

I checked the logs and found out that some jars from hadoop location are getting picked up. So tried unsetting the HADOOP_HOME env then it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You will get a more accurate reason for the observed error by inspecting the zookeeper node logs. By default the file is located at HBASE_HOME/logs/hbase--zookeeper-.out

Can you report the relevant parts of that file?

If you used the default properties as indicated in the HBase guide, it is possible you used /usr/local/zookeeper, which may not exist and/or don't have permission to write.